Count specific values across multiple columns based on data in another column
I have 2 table: Data and RC tables
Data table contains the orders with 3 codes



Order
RC1
RC2
RC3




1000
100
164
100


1001
134
100
null


1002
164
null
134



RC table containing the code descriptions:



RC
Description




100
Apple


134
Banana


164
Coconut



I would like to calculate how many times each RC appears in the Data table. In Excel it would be easy with a countif function but in DAX I'm stuck as it is pretty new for me.
Expected output:



RC
Description
Count




100
Apple
3


134
Banana
2


164
Coconut
2



I tried COUNTROWS & FILTER but I can count data only in the column where the relation is active between the two table (RC - RC1 OR RC2 OR RC3) so I think something is not okay with the relations (???) Can you please help me to find a solution for this problem?

It is much easier and simpler to deal with rows rather than columns with Power BI/DAX. I would recommend modifying your table in Power Query to like:



Order
Item
RC Id




1000
RC1
100


1000
RC2
164


1000
RC3
100


1001
RC1
134


1001
RC2
100


1002
RC1
164


1002
RC3
134



In Power Query, select your Order column and do a Unpivot Other Columns to get to this. From here, you then only need the one relationship.
Alternatively, if you keep to your original table structure, you need to create three relationships, one will be active and the other two will be inactive. Then you would use the USERELATIONSHIP function to activate each relationship in turn. Similar to:
RC Count = 
  var c1 = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('DataTable'), USERELATIONSHIP('RC'[RC]', DataTable'[RC1]) )
  var c2 = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('DataTable'), USERELATIONSHIP('RC'[RC]', DataTable'[RC2]) )
  var c3 = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('DataTable'), USERELATIONSHIP('RC'[RC]', DataTable'[RC3]) )

  return c1 + c2 + c3


Thank you @Sam Nseir! Both solution is working! :)
